# “Emergent magnetic monopole” discovered (5th December 2023)

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, magnetic-monopoles

Looks like a few days ago (5th December 2023) a research team discovered “emergent magnetic charge” in antiferromagnetic materials, and the result was published on [Nature Materials](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41563-023-01737-4).

The finding was also covered on other sites, often with less reserved titles, such as [this one](https://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/diamonds-and-rust-help-unveil-impossible-quasi-particles) on the website of Cambridge University (the institution with which the researchers are associated) that says

> Researchers have discovered magnetic monopoles – isolated magnetic charges – in a material closely related to rust…

What does “emergent magnetic monopole” mean here? Does this finding really show the existence of isolated magnetic monopoles?

Comment: General policy on this site is to *not* comment on the validity or otherwise of individual papers.  This is particularly the case or recently published paper.  I would, however, note the term ["quasi particle"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiparticle) here.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95913/2451

Comment: I interpret this question as "What are emergent  magnetic monopoles and have they been experimentally observed?", which does seem like a valid question to me.  You might want to edit the question to make this clear. Related: ["What is the mass of the emergent magnetic monopoles in spin ice and how is the mass of an emergent particle determined?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/36161/145491)

Comment: If I make an air bubble underwater, then in a lot of ways, it behaves like it effectively has negative mass, since it has less inertia than its environment. But that doesn't mean that I've discovered a fundamental particle with negative mass. Light is slowed down in glass, so I can make a particle that travels faster than light in glass. But that doesn't mean I've discovered a fundamental particle that breaks special relativity. The same reasoning applies to the purported magnetic monopole, as well as to anything you see from solid state physicists that gets published in Nature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put it simply, an emergent property is a property that stems from many parts of a system all working in some collaboration that produces a whole that is greater than the sum of its parts as it were.The second law of thermodynaimcs is an example of an emergent property of large particle ensembles.
The monoploes discovered in the recent research are not real paricles like those hypothesized by Dirac to explain the quantization of charge, they are "quasi-particles"; an emergent phenomenon produced by ordinary matter. So, no need to revise Maxwell's equations just yet!

Answer (score 3):

The word $\textit{emergent}$ is used in the condensed matter community to emphasize that it comes about from many-body physics. It's not a fundamental property of the elementary particles or atoms. I would say superconductivity and liquid water fall under emergent properties. So in your case $\textit{emergent}$ is a buzzword that is synonymous with $\textit{made in a material}$.

I only skimmed the nature paper, but I don't think the essential physics has changed in the past decade when I last looked into these. Magnetic monopoles in materials are formed from chains of magnetic dipoles. The magentic field mostly cancels along the chain. In a very loose cartoon picture, this makes the ends of the chain appear to look like monopoles. They are not of course. They are not "isolated magnetic charges".

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin that [magnetic monopoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) were [predicted by theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wu%E2%80%93Yang_monopole) in 1968 year,- almost **half century** ago.

Magnetic monopole can be formed only by a completely new elementary particles or quasi-particles, which was achieved in this mentioned research. They have noticed that in "topological defects rich" material, on the right conditions, quasi-particle [meron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meron_(physics)) can be created ("emergent" part) which is a collective alignment of spins towards/outwards a topological defect,- so called anti-clockwise/clockwise Bloch meron. Which basically is a magnetic $N/S$ monopole charge.

Comment: Could you add some more details on the meron and Wu-Yang monopole you mention, and how they connect to this research? Because I’m not well-acquainted with this topic, and your answer seems to disagree with Albertus’s.

Comment: My answer does not disagree with Albertus. Why you think it does ? Even in the mentioned research article it's mentioned that (citation): _Finally, we emphasize that the observation of emergent monopoles [...] does not violate Maxwell’s equation as they are_. I'm also not an expert in the field, just presented their research in a short summary. For the better understanding of research,- read the original nature article and related literature.

Comment: @Jono94 Quasi-particles are introduced to a wider audience in the book [N. Manton, P. Sutcliffe, *Topological Solitons*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/topological-solitons/0A9670253EB1C8254BDACA4EE30C3AA3).

Comment: @Jono94 This [talk](https://youtu.be/JsAo6QhREkQ?si=0zal_OT1nU5TiEyV&t=213) by N. Manton should also help.

Comment: @Vasiliauskas I was confused by your last sentence *”Which basically is a magnetic N/S monopole charge”*, because it seems to suggest this is indeed an isolated monopole, contrary to the other answers.

Comment: So, it seems you have misunderstood my post. Yes, its a magnetic monopole analog and NO, it's not isolated, but instead a collective behavior of system, that's why it's a property of a _quasi-particle_ meron. Quasi-particle means "open", not isolated, okay ?